# "Secure/Lockdown Window" for a program, windows 10

Tags: java, windows, security, javafx

I'm trying to think of how I should go about creating a 'Secure Window' for my JavaFX project. Essentially, the program would instead of displaying its content on the normal desktop, go into a secure mode where only the program is showing, you could not minimize and for example look at Google. This would mimic how many schools state testing programs work, if anyone is familiar. Just looking for some links or info to point me in the right direction, as I know this is possible, just not sure really what to look up. Thanks!

Comment: This sounds like a Windows-level configuration, not a JavaFX-level configuration.

Answer (score 2):

I would set the `Stage` to full screen, always on top and `StageStyle.UNDECORATED`. Then I would add an `EventFilter` for any `WindowEvent` and consume the event.

```
public class App extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        
        stage.initStyle(StageStyle.UNDECORATED);
        stage.setAlwaysOnTop(true);
        stage.setFullScreen(true);
        stage.addEventFilter(WindowEvent.ANY, Event::consume);
        stage.setFullScreenExitKeyCombination(KeyCombination.NO_MATCH);
        
        StackPane root = new StackPane();
        Scene scene = new Scene(root);
        
        stage.setScene(scene);

        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch();
    }

}
```

**Note:**  You still have keyboard issues, like Escape or Alt-Tab.

Comment: Removing `stage.setFullScreen(true);` would make it immune to alt-tab. However taskbar will be visible. Perhaps there's a terminal command in Windows 10  to hide the taskbar?

Comment: I haven't try to hide the task bar. If you find a way you should post it for future reference.

Answer (score 1):

You can essentially achieve this with 3 lines of code in your  initializer

```java
Rectangle2D visualBounds= Screen.getPrimary().getVisualBounds(); //Get the screen size
Scene scene = new Scene(root, visualBounds.getWidth(), visualBounds.getHeight());//Make sure the program fills length and width of the screen
primaryStage.setScene(scene);
primaryStage.setAlwaysOnTop(true);//Keeps it always on top
primaryStage.initStyle(StageStyle.UNDECORATED);//Remove the handy close/minimize buttons
primaryStage.show();
```

This'll make it really annoying for testing though, as soon as you hit run, it'll take over your screen. So make sure to have some way to safely exit the program from within the program. (If you don't mind terminating the program abruptly, you can always use alt+F4)

Edit:
I just tested it on a Windows 10 environment. Works like a charm. Not even task manager can come on top of it